# How to add target to Rails form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the `form_for` helper and would like it to submit to an iframe.

```
<%= form_for(section, :target => 'new_section_frame') do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I should then be able to call `$('form').submit()` and have the form submit to the iframe. It would work except that the target isn't present in the output html. The [Rails guide on form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) doesn't have this particular example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options for the `form_for` helper that pertain to html have to be in the html key. Like so:

```
<%= form_for(section, :html => {:target=>'new_section_frame'}) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is way shorter and should work in recent rails versions:

```
<%= form_for(section, target: '_new') %>
```