# Using target: "_blank" on button_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a button_tag in a modal. I want the button to open the link in a new window. I have tried using target: "_blank" but it doesn't work. I have tried using a link_to as well, but that doesn't even open the modal.

Here's my code in the view:

```
= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-lg btn-test") do
  Go <i class='icon-external-link'></i>
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Submitting the form redirects it to a new url, which should open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit a form to new window, use `target` attribute on `<form>` element:

```
<form action="" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I have mentioned above that target="_blank" isn't working for me. Please mention where in the button_tag I should put the target blank if you know about it. Thanks.

Comment: You need to put `target` in `form` element. Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413933/3603869 or https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/57141

Comment: I'm glad that your problem is solved :) Please accept the answer which has helped you the most.

Comment: Yes, I was waiting for the 2 mins of acceptance time to be over. :)